# Pass specific string to Java

Tags: java, android

The code I am using is from another programmer that I am implementing in my program.

This may be a rudimentary question, and will probably be "-1"'d, however I figured I would ask anyway...

**Code:**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("iqsrc://"+arguments.getText().toString())));
```

where the code starts the activity "startActivity" from an intent, sets the data, and gets the text to a string...I think that is what I am seeing.

I want to pass the argument ("iqsrc://"+arguments) to another java class where I can send it to a JNI library to return a string value to append to the TextView.

**My Question:** What am I passing? Am I passing a string or a parsed URI? How do I implement?

Possible implementation method:
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/17903120/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-a-java-class-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startActivity(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("iqsrc://"+arguments.getText().toString())));
```

Could be written like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String argument = "iqsrc://"+ arguments.getText().toString();
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(argument);
myIntent.setData(myUri);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

`("iqsrc://"+arguments.getText().toString())` is a `String`.
`Uri.parse("iqsrc://"+arguments)` is a `Uri`.

My guess is that you want the String.

Comment: thanks bud! So is the String am I reading (and going to be passing), is it called {"iqsrc://"} or is it called {"iqsrc://"+arguments}, or is it this whole thing {"iqsrc://"+ arguments.getText().toString()}?

Comment: String argument = "iqsrc://"+ arguments.getText().toString();
 // it's a string composed of two parts.  The + operator is simply concatenating the values

Comment: What @CSmith said. You need to store that string in a variable.